# How to set order clause

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
   DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) as [Month],
   sum(liftingbirds)[LiftingBirds],
   round(sum(totalweight),0)[Tot.Weight],
   round(sum(totalamount),0)[Tot.Amount],
   round(sum(totalweight)/sum(liftingbirds),2)[Avg.Weight],
   Round(Sum(Totalamount)/Sum(totalweight),2)[Avg.Rate] 
from k_LiftingEntryRecords 
where (liftingdate BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND getdate())
group by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE)  order by  DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE)
```

How to order. Where I have gone wrong . The o/p is coming like june,april,augst.
Desired op is april,june,july

Comment: just give as order by DATENAME asc

Comment: @Vamsi I tried thar but no use

Comment: You have to group by month(liftingdate) also followed by order by month(liftingdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) as [Month],sum(liftingbirds)[LiftingBirds],
   round(sum(totalweight),0)[Tot.Weight],
   round(sum(totalamount),0)[Tot.Amount],
   round(sum(totalweight)/sum(liftingbirds),2)[Avg.Weight],
   Round(Sum(Totalamount)/Sum(totalweight),2)[Avg.Rate]
   from k_LiftingEntryRecords where 
  (liftingdate BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND getdate())
   group by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) ,Month(liftingdate) 
   order by Month(liftingdate)
```

Try this.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
order by  DATEPART(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, But try this...

```
   select DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE) as [Month],sum(liftingbirds)[LiftingBirds],round(sum(totalweight),0)[Tot.Weight],
   round(sum(totalamount),0)[Tot.Amount],round(sum(totalweight)/sum(liftingbirds),2)[Avg.Weight],
   Round(Sum(Totalamount)/Sum(totalweight),2)[Avg.Rate] from k_LiftingEntryRecords where (liftingdate BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00.000' AND getdate())
   group by DATENAME(MONTH,LIFTINGDATE)  order by  LIFTINGDATE
```